# WCF on IIS incoming "invisible" requests issue

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, soap, java-io

this time I have a particular question.

I have a WCF exposed in our server. If you just call it from the browser, you can see the wsdl, so it is working.

Our partner has to call this WCF with a soap request (old, but this is a requirement). We don't see any request from their network, also in the IIS log.

Now, they told us our service returns "***java.io.IOException: Async IO operation failed (3), reason: RC: 107***".

I'm quite surprised, since, first of all, we wrote the WCF in C#, of course not Java. Further, how is it possible they send a request but we don't see it neither in the IIS log?

Comment: Probably, they wrote _their client_ in Java. A Java Exception from a SOAP Service makes no sense at all. And if you don't register any requests (even if they should fail) they probably have a bug on _their_ side.

Comment: Do you have a "Demo"-Client to prove your service is reachable and operational from outside? The error message hints to a connectivity problem. Is your server behind a firewall? Is their Client behind a firewall? Are all (necessary) ports reachable? ... I'd check that before touching code.

Comment: I got used to include a "Version" - Endpoint in my APIs, so I can fairly easily hack together a little "See, it works"-Client in any given language.

Comment: Anyone sending you a generic Java exception clearly doesn't understand what they are doing enough to explain what the actual problem is. It really does sound like a connectivity problem on their end, but there's nothing you can do with that error.

Comment: Thanks, you guys confirmed my doubts! :)

Comment: Is your service available via POST? (SOAP is POST, not GET) Try it using postman (http://www.getpostman.com/).

Answer (score 0):

The error

> java.io.IOException: Async IO operation failed (3), reason: RC: 107".

Is the error their client is throwing.

This means that the client call doesnt reach your endpoint.
There is very likely a network connection issue along the way.
Eg a firewall blocking the port , or blocking the origin of the call etc.
Some routing problem etc...

You may need to get a network guy to track why their call doesnt reach the your WCF service.